# Will the Constantinopole hard fork create new coins?

Tags: hardforks, constantinople

Is the ethereum constantinopole hard fork going to result in extra forked coins for ethereum holders?

Answer (score 6):

Constantinople is non-contentious. It wont create 2 forked chains, it's just an upgrade to the mainnet. It was however delayed yesterday, and will likely be postponed around a month.